# Can I change gmail's format of displaying messages? Would like subject on top & bolded

Tags: gmail

I recently updated form Droid Bionic to Droid Razr M.  Now that I have ICS, I have noticed that in the gmail app, the messages are listed with the sender in bold and on top and the subject line smaller and underneath.  This is very frustrating for me as its often the subject not the sender that I am looking for.  Is there a way to update this?

If not, is there a different app I could install that would be like the gmail app but give me this flexibility?

Comment: Gmail is a proprietary app that cannot be changed. Your only course of action is to look for an alternative email package :)

Answer (score 1):

In Gmail app I think there is no way to change the display format. You may try [K-9 Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9&hl=en).
It is the good email client for Android. It's incredibly powerful and 100% free
K-9 Mail is an open-source e-mail client with search, IMAP push email, multi-folder sync, flagging, filing, signatures, bcc-self, PGP, mail on SD & more!

[image]
[image]